# How to set an uv map, from an multiple uv, as primary one?

Tags: uv

Is it possible to set an uv map as primary one, in a multiple uv?
For exsample I want that map02 becomes map00 (primary map).
If it's possible, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can rename a UVMap in the [UVMaps panel](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/uv/layout_management.html), either double-click or <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>-click the name to edit it.

[image: uvmap list]

The little camera to the right of the name specifies the default map for blender, that is the one that is used if you do not select a specific UVMap.