# Material/Texture Problem

Tags: texturing, materials

I was rigging a character from Mario Kart and the model I got already contained materials for the meshes, I checked to see if the materials worked, and it did! so after following a tutorial on how to rig a model, I was fixing a weight paint problem and did the best I could to fix it, when I finally did and checked the material/texture, her whole body was brown instead of the material/texture it uses, I really don't want to start ALL over again with the weight paint process so hopefully this is fixable, thank you.[image]

Comment: can you please upload your .blend here? http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and attach it to the post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set an uv map, from an multiple uv, as primary one?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/122256/how-to-set-an-uv-map-from-an-multiple-uv-as-primary-one)

Comment: @ScottMilner that helped, but now the face turns gray

Comment: @Chris Yes. Blender has the limitation of only displaying a single UV mapping at a time in the viewport. It will still render fine.

Comment: @ScottMilner ok but before it displayed both UVs, now it renders with whichever has the camera clicked on

Comment: @Chris https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18346/texture-mapping-with-multiple-uv-maps